# AWS EC2 Instances: Launch Multiple Instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, servlets, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I want to create ec2 instances when ever the new user arrive. I created a servlet class to do this. When User arrive i check DB that is user new or not if new then create the instance and send back his/her IP. When i send http request to this servlet one by one for users i get the IP correctly. But when i send HTTP Call in parallel (for user1 send request in tab1, for user2 send request in tab2 simultaneously before getting response from user1 HTTP call). When i do this i got error. Sometimes user1 said

> "The instance ID 'i-0b79495934c3b5459' does not exist (Service:
>   AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInstanceID.NotFound;
>   Request ID: e18a9eaa-cb1b-4130-a3ee-bf1b19fa184c) "

And user2 send IP in response. Kindly help me What is the issue and how to resolve this.
This is the Servlet Class which i created.

```
public class GateKeeperController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(credentials);
    AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(awsCreds);
    RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest;
    RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult;
    Reservation reservation;
    Instance intstance;
    DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstanceRequest;
    DescribeInstancesResult describeInstanceResult;
    GatekeeperModal gateKeepermodal;
    String sourceAMI = null;
    String destinationAMI = null;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession s = request.getSession();
        String userID = (String) request.getParameter("userID");
        Double lattitude = Double.parseDouble((String) request.getParameter("lat"));
        Double lonitude = Double.parseDouble((String) request.getParameter("long"));
        if (userID != null) {
            Pair coordinates = new Pair(lattitude, lonitude);
            RegionSelection targetRegion = new RegionSelection();
            String regionResult = targetRegion.getRegion(coordinates);
            String instanceIP = null;
            gateKeepermodal = new GatekeeperModal();
            try {
                if (gateKeepermodal.checkUserIsNew(userID)) {
                    instanceIP = startInstance(userID, regionResult);
                    if (instanceIP != null) {
                        response.getWriter().write(instanceIP);
                    }
                } 
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    private String startInstance(String userID, String region) {
        String ami_id = new AMI().getAMI_ID(region);

        ec2Client.setEndpoint(region);
        runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();
        runInstancesRequest.withImageId(ami_id).withInstanceType("t2.micro").withMinCount(1).withMaxCount(1)
                .withKeyName("GateKeeper_User").withSecurityGroups("GateKeeper User");
        runInstancesResult = ec2Client.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
        reservation = runInstancesResult.getReservation();
        intstance = reservation.getInstances().get(0);
        String s1 = intstance.getState().getName();
        String s2 = InstanceStateName.Running.name();
        while (!s1.toLowerCase().equals(s2.toLowerCase())) {
            describeInstanceRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
            describeInstanceRequest.withInstanceIds(intstance.getInstanceId());
            ec2Client.setEndpoint(region);
            describeInstanceResult = ec2Client.describeInstances(describeInstanceRequest);
            reservation = describeInstanceResult.getReservations().get(0);
            intstance = reservation.getInstances().get(0);
            s1 = intstance.getState().getName();
            s2 = InstanceStateName.Running.name();
        }
        GateKeeperUser user = new GateKeeperUser(userID, intstance.getInstanceId(), intstance.getPublicIpAddress(),
                region);
        Boolean result;
        try {
            result = gateKeepermodal.createUser(user);
            if (result) {
                return intstance.getPublicIpAddress();
            } else {
                return null;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/query-api-troubleshooting.html#eventual-consistency):

> "If you successfully run the RunInstances command, and then
>   immediately run another command using the instance ID that was
>   provided in the response of RunInstances, it may return an
>   InvalidInstanceID.NotFound error. This does not mean the instance does
>   not exist. Some specific commands that may be affected are:
>   DescribeInstances: To confirm the actual state of the instance, run
>   this command using an exponential backoff algorithm.
>   TerminateInstances: To confirm the state of the instance, first run
>   the DescribeInstances command using an exponential backoff algorithm."